# Get position of float in an increasing sequence

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose given a ndarray t = [t_0, t_1, ..., t_p] of p+1 real numbers different and sorted.

I have another ndarray (bigger) T = [T_0, T_1, ..., T_N] of N+1 real numbers that all belong to [t_0, t_p].

What I want is the array [i_0, i_1, ..., i_N] of the (uniquely defined) indices i_j such that T_j belongs to [t_i_j, t_i_{j+1}[.

I can make things such that T would be sorted as well, if it helps. I would imagine that such a basic operation could be part of the numpy library, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy.searchsorted`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer No! It looks that it will do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul Panzer said in a comment, `np.searchsorted(t, T)` with optional `side` parameter to take care of the boundaries does exactly the job.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).